# Problema ao exibir itens em um qtablewidget

Tags: mysql, python

São preenchidas apenas as duas primeiras linhas da tabela, mas são preenchidos os números de linhas da tabela conforme o resultado da consulta e, no print exibe todos os itens normalmente,.

```
def escreveArquivo(self):
    con = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="pswd", db="cliente")
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute('select * from cliente;')
    rs = cursor.fetchall()
    result = self.ui.tableWidget
    result.setRowCount(len(rs))
    result.setColumnCount(5)

    row = 0

    for i in rs:
        result.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(i[1])))
        result.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(i[2])))
        result.setItem(row, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(i[3])))
        result.setItem(row, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(i[4])))
        result.setItem(row, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(i[5])))
        print(i)
        row =+ 1
```

Answer (score -1):

O problema foi resolvido da seguinte maneira:

```
row = row + 1
```